# Spring Boot Security: One user with multiple roles which has multiple permissions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-thymeleaf, userdetailsservice

Good day.

I am working on Spring Boot Security. I am stuck with a problem, and can't figure out how to implement `UserDetails` to grant authorities of a user with multiple roles, and each roles have different set of permissions.

For Example: Let's say **Mr. Keanu Reeves** has two roles with different set of permissions.

ID ----- ROLES ----------------- PERMISSIONS
1  ------ ROLE_JOHNWICK------ LOVE, SURVIVE, KILL
2  ------ ROLE_NEO------------- LOVE, SURVIVE

How can I grant authorities in `UserDetails`, so that **Mr. Keanu Reeves** can perform his role `ROLE_JOHNWICK` with permissions like `LOVE, SURVIVE, KILL` in one section, and in separate section he should perform `LOVE, SURVIVE` with the role `ROLE_NEO`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are a few ways to do that, I recommend that you read the [documentation about authorities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#authz-authorities). I think you'd have a complex `GrantedAuthority` and provide an implementation that consider the authorities that comes with the role. Another alternative would be to use the `RoleHierarchy`

Comment: Thanks @MarcusHertdaCoregio for your comment. ```RoleHierarchy``` isn't an option for me because, I have many dynamic roles to handle which comes from DB.